# Table of viscosity of water vs temperature

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, electrochemistry

[image]

Above is the table for water physical properties table with temperature related with a,v,b,Pr,Ra factor. This table has temperature only from 0 to 100. May I ask if there is a full table for this with a range of temperature from (-100 to 1000'C) on the web? I couldn't find any so I came here to ask for a little help.

Thank you and have a nice day!!

Comment: Have you searched CRC handbooks or Landolt Bornstein Hanbooks? There are a lot of handbooks on thermodynamic data. Not everything is online or freely available. A trip to a university library is a must. The range you are looking for is impractically huge. What is the state of water at 1000 C and under what pressure? What is the viscosity of ice?

Comment: A lot of similar data can be found in form of tables, charts or calculators at [Engineeringtoolbox](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/), [this link](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-dynamic-kinematic-viscosity-d_596.html) is particularly for liquid water up to critical T.

Comment: If you are looking for the liquid state over the quoted temperature range, you may have a problem below -21°C (the lowest possible liquid temperature, and that requires 200 MPa pressure) or above 374°C (the critical point). Does your table need to include vapor/gas?